# In Java, what is the best way to get each individual digit of an integer and its position for comparison?

Tags: java, string, algorithm

New to programming: In Java, what is the best way to get each individual digit of an Integer and its position for comparisons? For example, with an input of an Integer i = 12345, I'd like to preform a comparison operation on each individual digit 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. Since I can't get the index of the integer, I converted the integer to string, iterated, and used charAt().

```
String sI = Integer.toString(i);
for(int j = 0; j<i; j++){
    if(charAt(j)>n){
    //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to do and what problem you're facing.

Comment: @shmosel edited, is it more clearer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do the same solution however your loop may result in some unexpected errors. That's because `i` can be greater than the length of your String `sI`.

And `char`s in Java are integers too so the comparison may fail: for example the character value of `1` is `49` so a comparison like `if (sI.charAt(j) > 10)` will always results in `true`. So you have to re-convert your character to an integer with the `Character.getNumericValue()` function.

So I'd change the loop to the following:

```
String sI = Integer.toString(i);
for(int j = 0; j < sI.length(); j++){
    if(Character.getNumericValue(sI.charAt(j)) > n){
    //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `%`?

Comment: You mean `if(sI.charAt(j) % 48 > n)`? It is just a bad hack. Seems OK but it is hard to tell what `48` stands for if you just look at the code. I bet most of the developers do not know that `48` is the integer value of `'0'` and they don't have to know this. That's why such functions like `getNumericValue` exist.

Comment: No, I mean you can simply mod the original integer value itself to get the individual digits. I'm suggesting making it a string and then iterating over the numeric value of the characters is unnecessary.

Comment: That's true. However if he/she asked about how to do it with converting it to a string why not show how to do it properly that way? :) And yes, mod-ing the original integer is clearer like the solution of Bijoy but recursion is more complicated for a beginner than converting to a String and back.

Comment: Not trying to be argumentative here...they explain in the post that they went the string route due to an integer not being indexed. So, in a way they were looking for a way to index into an integer (e.g. `%`). It's perfectly OK to put OP on a "better" path. True, recursion can be troubling for a noob but anything that can be done recursively can be done with iterations (with sufficient ugliness).

Answer (score 4):

why not try this... you will know that your int is printing from the last digit so you'll know the position.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer temp = 123456789;
    do {
        System.out.println(temp % 10);
        temp = temp / 10;
    } while (temp % 10 > 0);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

May be something like this helps

```
public int findallIntegers(int x, int n) {
        if(x < 1) return 1;
        if(x%10 > n) {
            //do some thing
        }
        return findallIntegers(x/10, n);
    }
```